# Set UserAgent in http request

Tags: http-headers, go

I'm trying to make my Go application specify itself as a specific `UserAgent`, but can't find anything on how to go about doing this with `net/http`. I'm creating an `http.Client`, and using it to make `Get` requests, via `client.Get()`.

Is there a way to set the `UserAgent` in the Client, or at all?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

When creating your request use `request.Header.Set("key", "value")`:

```
package main

import (
        "io"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        client := &http.Client{}

        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://httpbin.org/user-agent", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Golang_Spider_Bot/3.0")

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        log.Println(string(body))

}
```

Result:

```
2012/11/07 15:05:47 {
  "user-agent": "Golang_Spider_Bot/3.0"
}
```

P.S. http://httpbin.org is amazing for testing this kind of thing!

Comment: There is a problem with using headers after redirect - they won't be used by default. You should provide custom function in Client.CheckRedirect field.

Comment: Just want to point out that while "Golang Spider Bot v. 3.0" is syntactically correct, it probably doesn't mean what you want. According to the spec, that means there are 5 product tokens: "Golang", "Spider", "Bot", "v.", and "3.0". Something more accurate would be "Golang_Spider_Bot/3.0"

see: http://www.bizcoder.com/the-much-maligned-user-agent-header

Comment: Combine with https://medium.com/@joshroppo/setting-go-1-5-variables-at-compile-time-for-versioning-5b30a965d33e to get that version to be dynamic